# Openstreetmap Tunnel

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid, tunnel

Is there any way to display all tunnel + road on OpenStreetMap ?
I am making a Bike Navigation system for trip.
in Tunnel, We lost GPS position , because there is no GPS data in tunnel.
I want to know timing when My position enter a tunnel and exit from the tunnel.

in OpenStreetMap, Is there any way to know Position of Tunnel Entry/Exit ?

Is this helpful ?
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:tunnel

from Tile Bitmap image, To know tunnel, it maybe not possible...
if I use original vector data of Openstreetmap, it maybe possible..
I am using android + osmdroid, then, it maybe not easy...

Please advice me .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [tunnel](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:tunnel) is the correct key. You definitely have to look at the raw (vector) data. The tunnel entry and exit is defined by the first and last [node](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node) of the tunnel [way](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way). Keep in mind that the tunnel can also be split into multiple adjacent ways.

Answer (score 0):

In generall `tunnel` tag will be associated with `layer` tag as well. To be more specific `layer=-1` tag is mostly used for the length of the tunnel.